# Feauture selection for clustering regarding zero-correlated feature

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, correlation

I want to cluster a 5 feature data-set. Firstly to explore the data I did a correlation matrix to see if some features where highly correlated so I could reduce them. Then I saw a feature that have close to zero correlation against all the other features. This got me wondering if I should exclude this parameter since it acts as a kind of "noise" relatively to all the other features. What's your opinion?

Comment: That feature *may* be a unique identifier (user number). **If** so, then you should ignore it, obviously.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse good point. At my case I know its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of correlation with other features is not a reason to omit a feature. On the contrary, it is usually a reason to keep the feature because it may provide unique information. Typically, highly correlated features provide redundant information and feature reduction techniques (e.g., [Principal Components Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)) are used to remove the redundancy.

While it is *possible* that the uncorrelated feature is noise, you should not make that assumption. It could be that the uncorrelated feature is the *only* one containing information and the other 4 features are all correlated noise.